# Why does the sort in this Microsoft SQL server query have 94% cost?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, query-optimization

I have this Linq to SQL query which is slow (2 seconds to return 1000 rows)

```
var listReceptacle = await((STTEntities)_unitOfWork.Context).IRTReceptacles
            .Include(r => r.Product)
            .Include(r => r.IRTEvents)
            .Where(r =>  r.IRTEvents.OrderByDescending(re => re.Timestamp)
            .Take(1)
            .Any(re => re.IRTEventTypeId == IRTEventType.InternalReceptacleCreated.Id
                    || re.IRTEventTypeId == IRTEventType.InternalReceptacleReOpened.Id
                    || re.IRTEventTypeId == IRTEventType.InternalReceptacleClosed.Id
                    || re.IRTEventTypeId == IRTEventType.InternalReceptacleIsPendingDispatch.Id
                )
            )
            .ToListAsync();
```

The tables are below.

1. There is a **receptacle**
2. which can have one or more **events** (e.g. receptacle created, receptacle closed, receptacle dispatched, delivered, etc.) associated with it
3. There is a table of **event types** (there are less than 20 event types)
4. Add a receptacle can be associated with one **product**.

[image]

The tables have indexes on these columns

**Receptacles**

```
   ID 
   Barcode
```

**Events**

```
   ID
   EventTypeID
   ReceptacleID
   Timestamp
```

**Event types**

```
   ID
   Code - must be unique
```

Actual exection plan in paste bin: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1dRIdkN6

The actual execution plan of a SQL query shows a sort block which has 94% costs.

Here is an extract of the actual execution plan (I've pasted the entire plan at the bottom)

[image: Extract of actual execution plan]

Hovering over the sort block shows

[image]

I've added below indexes in the events table but the sort block still has 94% cost.

1. composite index on columns EventTypeId + Timestamp
2. composite index on columns Id + Timestamp
3. index on Timestamp with included column EventTypeId

Code:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IRTEvents_IRTEventTypeId_TimeStamp] 
ON [dbo].[IRTEvents] ([IRTEventTypeId] ASC, [TimeStamp] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IRTEvents_Id_TimeStamp] 
ON [dbo].[IRTEvents] ([Id] ASC, [TimeStamp] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IRTEvents_TimeStamp_2] 
ON [dbo].[IRTEvents] ([TimeStamp] DESC)
INCLUDE (IRTEventTypeId)
```

This is the query (generated by Linq)

```
USE SwiftTrackAndTrace
DECLARE @p__linq__0 INT = 1 
DECLARE @p__linq__1 INT = 3 
DECLARE @p__linq__2 INT = 2 
DECLARE @p__linq__3 INT = 6 
SELECT
        [Project3].[Id]                        AS [Id]                       ,
        [Project3].[Barcode]                   AS [Barcode]                  ,
        [Project3].[AllowedProductId]          AS [AllowedProductId]         ,
        [Project3].[DestinationLocationId]     AS [DestinationLocationId]    ,
        [Project3].[Id1]                       AS [Id1]                      ,
        [Project3].[ProductGroupId]            AS [ProductGroupId]           ,
        [Project3].[Code]                      AS [Code]                     ,
        [Project3].[Description]               AS [Description]              ,
        [Project3].[Rowversion]                AS [Rowversion]               ,
        [Project3].[ValidateCheckDigit]        AS [ValidateCheckDigit]       ,
        [Project3].[AllowCustom]                AS [AllowCustom]  ,
        [Project3].[ImportInfo]                 AS [ImportInfo],
        [Project3].[NewItem]                   AS [NewItem]    ,
        [Project3].[IsActive]                  AS [IsActive]                 ,
        [Project3].[C1]                        AS [C1]                       ,
        [Project3].[Id2]                       AS [Id2]                      ,
        [Project3].[IRTReceptacleId]           AS [IRTReceptacleId]          ,
        [Project3].[IRTEventTypeId]            AS [IRTEventTypeId]           ,
        [Project3].[TIMESTAMP]                 AS [TIMESTAMP]                ,
        [Project3].[LocationId]                AS [LocationId]               
        --[Project3].[UserId]                    AS [UserId]
FROM
        (
                SELECT
                        [Extent1].[Id]                                                       AS [Id]                       ,
                        [Extent1].[Barcode]                                                  AS [Barcode]                  ,
                        [Extent1].[AllowedProductId]                                         AS [AllowedProductId]         ,
                        [Extent1].[DestinationLocationId]                                    AS [DestinationLocationId]    ,
                        [Extent2].[Id]                                                       AS [Id1]                      ,
                        [Extent2].[ProductGroupId]                                           AS [ProductGroupId]           ,
                        [Extent2].[Code]                                                     AS [Code]                     ,
                        [Extent2].[Description]                                              AS [Description]              ,
                        [Extent2].[Rowversion]                                               AS [Rowversion]               ,
                        [Extent2].[ValidateCheckDigit]                                       AS [ValidateCheckDigit]       ,
                        [Extent2].[AllowCustom]                                             AS [AllowCustom]  ,
                        [Extent2].[ImportInfo]                                              AS [ImportInfo],
                        [Extent2].[NewItem]                                                 AS [NewItem]    ,
                        [Extent2].[IsActive]                                                 AS [IsActive]                 ,
                        [Extent3].[Id]                                                       AS [Id2]                      ,
                        [Extent3].[IRTReceptacleId]                                          AS [IRTReceptacleId]          ,
                        [Extent3].[IRTEventTypeId]                                           AS [IRTEventTypeId]           ,
                        [Extent3].[TIMESTAMP]                                                AS [TIMESTAMP]                ,
                        [Extent3].[LocationId]                                               AS [LocationId]               ,
                        --[Extent3].[UserId]                                                   AS [UserId]                   
                        CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS INT) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
                FROM
                        [dbo].[IRTReceptacles] AS [Extent1]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2]
                ON
                        [Extent1].[AllowedProductId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        [dbo].[IRTEvents] AS [Extent3]
                ON
                        [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[IRTReceptacleId]
                WHERE
                        EXISTS
                        (
                                SELECT
                                        1 AS [C1]
                                FROM
                                        (
                                                SELECT
                                                        TOP (1) [Project1].[IRTEventTypeId] AS [IRTEventTypeId]
                                                FROM
                                                        (
                                                                SELECT
                                                                        [Extent4].[IRTEventTypeId] AS [IRTEventTypeId],
                                                                        [Extent4].[TIMESTAMP]      AS [TIMESTAMP]
                                                                FROM
                                                                        [dbo].[IRTEvents] AS [Extent4]
                                                                WHERE
                                                                        [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[IRTReceptacleId] ) AS [Project1]
                                                ORDER BY
                                                        [Project1].[TIMESTAMP] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
                                WHERE
                                        [Limit1].[IRTEventTypeId] IN (@p__linq__0,
                                                                      @p__linq__1,
                                                                      @p__linq__2,
                                                                      @p__linq__3) ) ) AS [Project3]
ORDER BY
        [Project3].[Id] ASC ,
        [Project3].[Id1] ASC,
        [Project3].[C1] ASC
```

[image: Entire actual execution plan]

Comment: The "Cost" part of the query plan is honestly best ignored. If you want to share query plans as well, please use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), as we can then inspect the plan.

Comment: I've added the paste bin link (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1dRIdkN6)  in the question

Comment: @Thom A
 : that's not entirely true. The relative cost can be important .

Comment: @MitchWheat - the operator timings are more reliable, e.g, in this case the eager spool looks like the problem not the sort. Despite the operator costs

Comment: @MitchWheat The cost shown is based on estimate though, so while it *can* be important, it can also be very misleading. In this case sort takes less than 0.1s which is not a significant portion of the execution time. The real cost is in the eager spool which shows as 4% estimated cost, but accounts for significantly more of the actual cost.

Comment: The timings are inclusive timings in this case 2.352 - 2.271s is 0.081 seconds to give the time contributed by the sort rather than its children

Comment: yep, I always forget they are cumulative!

Comment: In batch mode plans the timings can be non cumulative though!

Comment: Part of the problem liekly is that none of your indexes are covering; you are asking for more columns from the table(s) than your indexes are sorted on or `INCLUDE` (for example `LocationId` and `IRTReceptacleId` aren't in any of your indexes for `IRTEvents`, but you return then in your `SELECT`). As a result the database engine has determined that a scan of the *entire* table is more performant than a seek of what it *can* do and then a key lookup.

Comment: The exists itself is basically redundant, the latest event could be worked out using just the existing joins using something like `LAST_VALUE([Extent3].[IRTEventTypeId]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Extent3].[IRTReceptacleId] ORDER BY [Extent3].[TIMESTAMP])`, then this can be filtered for your specified IDs; but I honestly have no idea how to coerce Linq into creating this SQL. I've tried and failed in my tests. This is one reason many end up using things like Dapper, or even just the Raw SQL functions in EF. Sometimes you need a bit more control over the generated SQL to produce efficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

You better to use `join` instead of that complex `any` condition:

- First, create a queryable from IRTEvent grouped by IRTReceptacleId, and select IRTReceptacleId and max(Timestamp).
- Then, `join` the queryable to both IRTReceptacle (on IRTReceptacleId) and IRTEvent (on IRTReceptacleId and Timestamp) to check the condition on IRTEventTypeId.
- Eliminate records that have the same IRTReceptacleId and Timestamp by using `distinct`.